# Can anyone explain me this code in building machine learning systems with python?

Tags: python, matplotlib, machine-learning, scipy

Why is the error function used and how is return value calculated?
What are the functions of polyfit and poly1d?

```
import scipy as sp
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
data = sp.genfromtxt("web_traffic.tsv", delimiter="\t")
x = data[:,0]
y = data[:,1]
x = x[~sp.isnan(y)]
y = y[~sp.isnan(y)]

def error(f, x, y):
     return sp.sum((f(x)-y)**2)
fp1, residuals, rank, sv, rcond = sp.polyfit(x, y, 1, full=True)
f1 = sp.poly1d(fp1)
fx = sp.linspace(0,x[-1], 1000) # generate X-values for plotting
plt.plot(fx, f1(fx), linewidth=1)
# plt.legend(["d=%i" % f1.order], loc="upper left")
plt.scatter(x,y)
plt.title("Web traffic over the last month")
plt.xlabel("Time")
plt.ylabel("Hits/hour")
plt.xticks([w*7*24 for w in range(10)],
['week %i'%w for w in range(30)])
plt.autoscale(tight=True)
plt.grid()
plt.show()
```

Comment: [Here](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/luispedro/BuildingMachineLearningSystemsWithPython/master/ch01/data/web_traffic.tsv) is a link to the data file for anyone who wants to test this code.

Comment: Did you mean to include more code? `error` isn't used and this just looks like an example of curve fitting..

Answer (score 0):

This looks like it's based on the [supporting code](https://github.com/luispedro/BuildingMachineLearningSystemsWithPython/blob/master/ch01/analyze_webstats.py) for the book *["Building Machine Learning Systems with Python"](http://www.amazon.co.uk/Building-Machine-Learning-Systems-Python/dp/1782161406)*.

The `error` function is used to print squared error values (a measure of the actual values variance from the fitted curve) for a list of curve fitting functions in a part of the code which has been omitted/removed.

Here's the code which actually uses the `error` function:

```
print("Errors for the complete data set:")
for f in [f1, f2, f3, f10, f100]:
    print("Error d=%i: %f" % (f.order, error(f, x, y)))

print("Errors for only the time after inflection point")
for f in [f1, f2, f3, f10, f100]:
    print("Error d=%i: %f" % (f.order, error(f, xb, yb)))

print("Error inflection=%f" % (error(fa, xa, ya) + error(fb, xb, yb)))
```

The return value is squared because the error (distance from the fitted curve to the actual data point) could be positive or negative depending on whether it's above or below the curve. Just summing these up would mean that the errors could cancel each other out and make it look like a function is a better fit that it really is.

The solution is squaring the error, since squaring a negative number gives you a positive number, so they can then be summed up to give a measure of the error for each curve-fitting function.

Comment: No problem. You can upvote answers that helped you out, and accept the best one (can be best to wait a while to see if any better answers arrive).

Comment: Could you please explain why is the return value squared?

Comment: This really helped me. Thanks!

Answer (score -1):

The `error` function isn't actually being used in this code at all (you can delete it and the code works absolutely fine). If you did use it it would give you a measure of how well the values in `y` approximated those in `f(x)`. Roughly speaking if this number is lower your approximation is good and if it is higher the approximation is bad.

The function `sp.polyfit` is used to generate a polynomial of best fit through the data. Basically it tries to find the polynomial function which best approximates the data you give it. The `1` argument tells it to generate a polynomial of order 1 which is a straight line.

Once it's found the line of best fit it returns it as an array of coefficients so if the function it found was f(x) = 1 + 2x then it would return `array([1,2])`. The poly1d function takes this array of coefficients and generates a callable object (effectively a function). Basically this lets you go from `array([1,2])` to `f`. This object is useful because it lets you plot the function.

For more information:

1. [Documentation for polyfit](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.polyfit.html)
2. [Documentation for poly1d](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.poly1d.html)

Comment: Could you please explain why is the return value squared?

Comment: Thank you for the great explanation!

Comment: @Sourabhunofficial We square things to work out the error in analogy with Pythagoras' theorem. If you imagine the actual function `f(x)` and the calculated values `y` are two vectors which live in a `len(x)` dimensional space then the value returned by `error` will be the square of the length of the vector that joins them to make a triangle. Because we put things to the power of 2 we call this measure of distance the 2-norm. Generally we use it because it works pretty well...